# I have a problem with creating a list of data in python, can you help me?

Tags: python, list

I want a list with 8 columns
This is my code

```
empleadonum =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
nombre_empleado = ['Juan Medina', 'Lucho Espino', 'Jose Alejandro', 'Sebastian Sandoval', 'Maria Rodriguez', 'Jacky Zamora', 'Ernesto Dominguez', 'Nahuel Damitra', 'Maria ALejandra', 'Arnaldo Moreno']
cedula =  ['7-711-2153', '123123123', '23231231', '2132123', '2326566', '123655', '56567244', '12312312', '8779898', '1231231']
horastrabajadas =  [25.0, 20.0, 20.1, 30.2, 56.3, 21.3, 20.2, 40.1, 21.0, 21.0]
pagoporhora = 7.5
salariobruto = 0.0
segurosocial = 0.0
n=0
print( "{:<10} {:<10} {:<10} {:<10} {:<10} {:<10} {:<10} {:<10}" .format ('ID','Nombre', 'Cédula', 'Horas trabajadas', 'Pago por hora', 'Salario bruto', 'Total deducciones', 'Sueldo por pagar'))
while n < 10:
    salariobruto =horastrabajadas[n]*8.1
    segurosocial = salariobruto*0.0975
    seguroeducativo = salariobruto * 0.0125
    impuestorenta = salariobruto * 0.10
    totaldeducciones = segurosocial + seguroeducativo + impuestorenta
    salariofinal = salariobruto - totaldeducciones
    print("{:<10} {:<10} {:<10} {:<10} {:<10} {:<10} {:<10} {:<10}".format(n, nombre_empleado, cedula, horastrabajadas, pagoporhora, salariobruto, totaldeducciones, salariofinal))
    n=n+1
print("gracias")
```

My output is an error: unsupported format string passed to list.**format**

Comment: You cannot directly pass in a list in format. You probably would be better off checking out the `pandas` library when working with these structures like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass a list, and `horastrabajadas` is a list.

You can use `str(horastrabajadas)` to mitigate this.

Comment: It's a `list`, not an `array`.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip()` + for-loop to iterate over rows and print formatted string:

```py
empleadonum = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
nombre_empleado = [
    "Juan Medina",
    "Lucho Espino",
    "Jose Alejandro",
    "Sebastian Sandoval",
    "Maria Rodriguez",
    "Jacky Zamora",
    "Ernesto Dominguez",
    "Nahuel Damitra",
    "Maria ALejandra",
    "Arnaldo Moreno",
]
cedula = [
    "7-711-2153",
    "123123123",
    "23231231",
    "2132123",
    "2326566",
    "123655",
    "56567244",
    "12312312",
    "8779898",
    "1231231",
]
horastrabajadas = [25.0, 20.0, 20.1, 30.2, 56.3, 21.3, 20.2, 40.1, 21.0, 21.0]
pagoporhora = 7.5
salariobruto = 0.0
segurosocial = 0.0
n = 0

print(
    "{:<10} {:<20} {:<15} {:<20} {:<15} {:<20} {:<20} {:<15}".format(
        "ID",
        "Nombre",
        "Cédula",
        "Horas trabajadas",
        "Pago por hora",
        "Salario bruto",
        "Total deducciones",
        "Sueldo por pagar",
    )
)


for e, n, c, h in zip(empleadonum, nombre_empleado, cedula, horastrabajadas):
    salariobruto = h * 8.1
    segurosocial = salariobruto * 0.0975
    seguroeducativo = salariobruto * 0.0125
    impuestorenta = salariobruto * 0.10
    totaldeducciones = segurosocial + seguroeducativo + impuestorenta
    salariofinal = salariobruto - totaldeducciones

    print(
        "{:<10} {:<20} {:<15} {:<20} {:<15} {:<20.2f} {:<20.2f} {:<15.2f}".format(
            e,
            n,
            c,
            h,
            pagoporhora,
            salariobruto,
            totaldeducciones,
            salariofinal,
        )
    )
```

Prints:

```
ID         Nombre               Cédula          Horas trabajadas     Pago por hora   Salario bruto        Total deducciones    Sueldo por pagar
1          Juan Medina          7-711-2153      25.0                 7.5             202.50               42.53                159.97         
2          Lucho Espino         123123123       20.0                 7.5             162.00               34.02                127.98         
3          Jose Alejandro       23231231        20.1                 7.5             162.81               34.19                128.62         
4          Sebastian Sandoval   2132123         30.2                 7.5             244.62               51.37                193.25         
5          Maria Rodriguez      2326566         56.3                 7.5             456.03               95.77                360.26         
6          Jacky Zamora         123655          21.3                 7.5             172.53               36.23                136.30         
7          Ernesto Dominguez    56567244        20.2                 7.5             163.62               34.36                129.26         
8          Nahuel Damitra       12312312        40.1                 7.5             324.81               68.21                256.60         
9          Maria ALejandra      8779898         21.0                 7.5             170.10               35.72                134.38         
10         Arnaldo Moreno       1231231         21.0                 7.5             170.10               35.72                134.38
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is: You are using `list` in the `format()` function used in `print` statement.
Here is the code which works:

```
empleadonum =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
nombre_empleado = ['Juan Medina', 'Lucho Espino', 'Jose Alejandro', 'Sebastian Sandoval', 'Maria Rodriguez', 'Jacky Zamora', 'Ernesto Dominguez', 'Nahuel Damitra', 'Maria ALejandra', 'Arnaldo Moreno']
cedula =  ['7-711-2153', '123123123', '23231231', '2132123', '2326566', '123655', '56567244', '12312312', '8779898', '1231231']
horastrabajadas =  [25.0, 20.0, 20.1, 30.2, 56.3, 21.3, 20.2, 40.1, 21.0, 21.0]
pagoporhora = 7.5
salariobruto = 0.0
segurosocial = 0.0
n=0
print( "{:<10} {:<10} {:<10} {:<10} {:<10} {:<10} {:<10} {:<10}" .format ('ID','Nombre', 'Cédula', 'Horas trabajadas', 'Pago por hora', 'Salario bruto', 'Total deducciones', 'Sueldo por pagar'))
while n < 10:
    salariobruto = horastrabajadas[n]*8.1
    segurosocial = salariobruto*0.0975
    seguroeducativo = salariobruto * 0.0125
    impuestorenta = salariobruto * 0.10
    totaldeducciones = segurosocial + seguroeducativo + impuestorenta
    salariofinal = salariobruto - totaldeducciones
    print("{:<10} {:<20} {:<15} {:<20} {:<15} {:<20.2f} {:<20.2f} {:<15.2f}".format(n, nombre_empleado[n], cedula[n], horastrabajadas[n], pagoporhora, salariobruto, totaldeducciones, salariofinal))
    n=n+1
print("gracias")
```

`nombre_empleado`, `cedula` and `horastrabajadas` are of type `list`, hence the error, you will have to pass index `n` in this case to read the value at that particular index.